# Have u-boot run a script upon startup without the use of console

Tags: startup, u-boot

I am trying to use u-boot to load my OS over NFS, but the platform that I'm running u-boot on does not have a serial port output. Because of that, I cannot use the u-boot command line.

I know you can define the value of `bootcmd` to whatever you'd like executed as an autorun, but all the guides I've read suggest setting the envvar from the command line. Since this isn't possible for me, are there other ways I could set this variable, e.g. from `make menuconfig` or from source code hacking?

Comment: In your board's configuration file, e.g. **include/configs/myboard.h**, simply define a string for **CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND** to set the environment variable **bootcmd** in the default environment.  Note that the default environment is not used if the non-volatile copy of the environment is deemed valid (i.e. has a correct CRC32).

Answer (score 1):

If U-Boot was build with CONFIG_DISTRO_DEFAULTS=y just place a u-boot.scr or u-boot.scr.uimg file on the boot partition.

Some older U-Boot versions were looking for uEnv.txt.